# I have buyed a 750 rpm torque 3kg.cm motor but i am not able to calculate the amount of torque and rpm avilable on 7cm tyre

Tags: power, motor, stepper-motor, torque

This is the motor i buyed 
http://www.snapdeal.com/product/core-dc-helical-geared-motor/719331155

I am working on project for science fair but it has become too much confusion that how much weight and rpm does this motor will provide when attached to a 8cm Tyre please help it is very important.

The motor rpm is 750 and torque is 3 kg.cm 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your motor doesn't appear to have much in the way of data. A torque-speed graph is needed to inform properly: -

[image]

Most reputable motors and suppliers will have these graphs. The problem you have is that you have a quoted torque of 3 kg.cm but you don't know if that is the intermittent torque for stall situations or the rated torque for continuous operations.

If it is the rated continuous torque then this is a force equivalent to the weight of 3kg at a radius of 1cm. If you have an 8cm diameter wheel then the force at a radius of 4cm is one quarter this value.

Comment: yes i know that is the problem i can just tell that it is 12v dc and torque that is why i am confused please help me

Comment: How can I help you any more. Maybe I can .... Buy a motor with a clear technical specification and if it has a PDF data sheet then try and find it. I'm not going to go looking for it .